# Problems understanding how to reference a parent class in php

Tags: php, oop

New to OOP so sorry if this is obvious.

I have a class and a child class

```
class dBConnect {

private $host, $username, $password, $database, $input;

public function __construct($host, $username, $password, $database){
    $this->host        = $host;
    $this->username    = $username;
    $this->password    = $password;
    $this->database    = $database;


    $this->dbConnect = new mysqli( $this->host, $this->username, $this->password, $this->database);
    /* check connection */
    if (mysqli_connect_errno()) {
        printf("Connect failed: %s\n", mysqli_connect_error());
        exit();
        }
    return true;
}

public function setCharacterSet($charSet = 'utf8'){
   if(!$this->dbConnect->set_charset($charSet)){
    printf("Error loading character set ".$charSet.": %s\n", $this->dbConnect->error);   
    };
    return true;
    }


   public function sanitizeSQL($input){
   return(mysqli_real_escape_string($this->dbConnect, $input));
   }

   public function runQuery($query) {
     $result = $this->dbConnect->query($query);
       if (!$result) die('Invalid query: ' . mysql_error($this->dbConnect));
      return $result;
      }

public function __destruct() {
    mysqli_close($this->dbConnect)
        OR die("There was a problem disconnecting from the database.");

   }

 }

 class newUser extends dBConnect {

    public static function login($userName=NULL, $password=NULL) {

       $sql = "SELECT * FROM db26541116_farmFile.users WHERE userName = '".$userName."' AND password = '".$password."' LIMIT 0,1";
       $result=parent::runQuery($sql);
      $numRows = $result->num_rows;
    $result->close();
    if($numRows > 0){
      return false;
    }else{
    $sql = "INSERT INTO db26541116_farmFile.users (userName, password) VALUES  ('$userName', '$password')"; 
    $result=parent::runQuery($sql);
    $result->close();
    return true;    
    }

    throw new RuntimeException("NULL string found in cleanPostString");

}

}
```

I can create the object

```
      $db = new dBConnect("localhost", "userName", "password", "database");
      $db->setCharacterSet('utf8');
```

without issue but when I use the child class I have issues

```
    if(newUser::login($userName,$passWord)){
//send to site
}else{
//try again 
}
```

I get the error Non-static method dBConnect::runQuery() should not be called statically. How should I call the parent class from within newUser.

Thanks in anticipation.

Comment: `$this->runQuery()` not parent

Comment: You may want to 1) change your database credentials and 2) in the future not share them with the community

Comment: you clearly do not know the difference between static classes and objects. google a tutorial for this

Comment: static classes in php?

Comment: As a word of advise your `newUser` class should probably not be extending the `dBConnect` . If anything you should be passing in the connection. This is pretty tight coupling of models and persistence.

Answer (score 0):

```
$result=parent::runQuery($sql);
```

Error is in this line. You have defined the runQuery as public function so you should call it using `$this->`. If you have defined it as public static then you can call it like `parent::`.

The same error will occure on this line:

```
$result=parent::runQuery($sql);
```

You should not call methods that are not static in static once. The opposite is not true - you can call static method in non static one. You should read the php documentation for more information.

Comment: That's what I've mentioned in the last 2 rows.

Answer (score 0):

You should instantiate the newUser class instead of the parent class. And use its object to login the user.

```
$newUser = new newUser("localhost", "farmFile01", "NheuYyjadk3hdCga", "db26541116_farmFile"); // will use the construct of the parent class
$newUser->setCharacterSet('utf8'); 
if(newUser->login($userName,$passWord)){
//send to site
}else{
//try again 
}
```

Or maybe better, not extend the database class but pass the database object like this.

```
$newUser = new newUser($db);
```

In combination with

```
class newUser extends dBConnect {
  private $db;
  public function __construct($db){
  $this->db = $db;
  }
}
// and to run a query use 
$result=$this->db->runQuery($sql);
```

Answer (score 0):

You Can change your code like this :

```
if(newUser::login($userName,$passWord,$db)){
//send to site
}else{
//try again 
}
```

In Your newUser Class you need to change like this

```
public static function login($userName=NULL, $password=NULL,newUser $newUser) {
 $result=$newUser->runQuery($sql);
}
```

and then your code will work fine.

Answer (score 0):

Aside from some errors in your code to solve this issue below should outline the issue and give you a place to go.

The way you call the method you have created is actually like this:

```
//No instantiation needed ie $newUser = new newUser()
//It is static so you can just call it.
newUser::login();
```

However you will get an error `Non-static method dBConnect::runQuery() should not be called statically`

This is because to call `dbConnect`'s `runQuery($sql)` you have to instantiate an instance of that object. `newUser` extends it so that is technically what you need to create.

```
$newUser = new newUser('host','user','pass','db'); //Notice this is dbConnects constructor.
$newUser->login();
```

But again you will get the error `Non-static method dBConnect::runQuery() should not be called statically` because you are still calling this from within a static method.

So the solution is pretty simple remove the `static` identifier from your method `login`. You could technically leave it alone at this point but you will probably want to update `parent::runQuery($sql);` to `$this->runQuery($sql);` because calling `parent` would get `dbConnect`'s `runQuery($sql)` and lets say one day you need to override that in `newUser` you will be fighting a bug and not know why.

As a note `$this` is short for this instance of an object and is not available to static methods. Static methods are not part of an instance but rather the object itself. Since you do not have to have an instantiate of an object to use the method there is no this instance.